# PostgreSQL: Where does it save data for uncommited transactions

Tags: postgresql

I'm about to load huge date from a large text file to a postgresql database, I searched on the internet that the best way to insert about 100k row is to make a single transaction and commit at the end of all my process as [this article explain](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/04/speeding-up-saving-millions-of-orm.htmlhttp://blog.endpoint.com/2014/04/speeding-up-saving-millions-of-orm.html?m=1)

So I want to know where is the Transaction is stored before the commit?  on the memory ? , on disk ?

Comment: Not yet committed changes are stored on whatever medium the table is on. Most likely to disk. The RDBMS uses isolation levels (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) to determine which transaction scopes can see which changes. In a general sense, where those changes reside should be transparent to data consumers.

Comment: thx, I want to be sure that its saved on the disk, because I have memory limits